# How to send server side jquery datatable data to the server using post request

Tags: c#, datatables

I am using server side jquery datatable and i used the simple ajax get request and accessed jquery datatable data(like:start,draw,order,search) in my c# program.But now i have many columns so its not returing data of all datatable columns using get request so i want to use the ajax post request but i don't know how to access these datatable parameters(start,draw,order,search) and pass these in ajax post request.

**GET Request**:
**Client Side**

```
 "ajax": "/Admin/InterestsJson"
```

**Server Side:** C#

```
NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
string sEcho = nvc["draw"];
int iDisplayStart = Convert.ToInt32(nvc["start"]);
string searchValue = nvc["search[value]"];
int orderColumn = Convert.ToInt32(nvc["order[0][column]"]);
string orderDir = nvc["order[0][dir]"];
```

**Post Request:Client side**

```
"ajax": {
"url": "/Admin/SubInterestsJson",
"type": "POST"
}
```

Please tell me how to access these jquet datatable parameters and pass in post request?

Comment: You have already changed request type to `POST` with `"type": "POST"`. DataTables will pass these parameters for you if you enable server-side processing mode with `"serverSide": true"`.

Comment: i already using bServerSide": true but not getting the values on server side

Answer (score 7):

**For POST request:**

If you are sending POST request, use the following code on the server side like:

```
string sEcho = Request.Params["draw"];
int iDisplayStart = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["start"]);
string searchValue = Request.Params["search[value]"];
int orderColumn = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["order[0][column]"]);
string orderDir = Request.Params["order[0][dir]"];
```

**For GET request:**

The following code is what I used before for GET request.

```
NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
string sEcho = nvc["draw"];
int iDisplayStart = Convert.ToInt32(nvc["start"]);
string searchValue = nvc["search[value]"];
int orderColumn = Convert.ToInt32(nvc["order[0][column]"]);
string orderDir = nvc["order[0][dir]"];
```